# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get a user's zip code from http://ip-api.com/json in javascript. The header the website sends to the client includes the following line:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

I assume the above line means that cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is enabled by the server. However, when I run the following code snippet, I get an error message in Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HttpRequestJson() {
            const http_url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
            const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", http_url, false); // false => synchronous
            xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/json");

            xmlhttp.send();

            const jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(jsonObj.zip);

            return jsonObj.zip;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <script>
        alert(HttpRequestJson());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The error message returned by Firefox is:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ip-api.com/json. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

The weird problem is that I do not get an error message all the time. In other words, sometimes I get the right zip code and sometimes I get the said error. Usually, when I open Firefox for the first time, I do not get the error while reloading the page returns an error.

What are some issues that could lead to the aforementioned error?

P.S. I would like to make this request synchronous. However, an asynchronous request would lead to the same error.

**Update 1**

I have a similar issue in Chrome. The first time the page is loaded the zip code is returned, but the next times I get the following errors:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://ip-api.com/json'.

Comment: Are you sending more than 150 requests within a minute? if yes then this is what I got from their documentation page "Usage limits
This endpoint is limited to 150 requests per minute from an IP address. If you go over this limit your IP address will be blackholed.
Check if IP is banned and unban for 
We do not allow commercial use of this endpoint. Please see our pro service for SSL access, unlimited queries and commercial support." You can unban your ip address easily. http://ip-api.com/docs/unban

Comment: No, I'm sending less than 10 requests per minute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like this issue was due to using an ad blocker.